# Any lips images

Tags: code-golf, number, graphical-output

## Introduction

The [**\$n\$-ellipse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) is a generalization of the ellipse with possibly more than two foci. Specifically, given \$n\$ points on the plane, called foci, the \$n\$-ellipse is the set of points of the plane whose sum of distances to the \$n\$ foci is equal to a constant \$t\$.

This challenge is about plotting the \$n\$-ellipse together with its **interior**; that is, the set of points whose sum of distances to the \$n\$ foci is **less than or equal to** equal to \$t\$. Note that the resulting set is always convex.

To simplify, only points with **integer coordinates**  need to be considered.

## The challenge

**Input**:

- Number of points \$n\$: positive integer;
- List of \$n\$ foci (possibly repeated) with integer coordinates, \$(x_1, y_1)\$, ..., \$(x_n, y_n)\$;
- Threshold \$t\$: positive integer.

**Output**:

An **image** representing all points \$P\$ with integer coordinates such the sum of Euclidean distances from \$P\$ to the \$n\$ foci is less than or equal to \$t\$.

Each pixel in the image should correspond to a point with integer coordinates; that is, **pixel size** is \$1 \times 1\$. Alternatively, you can use a **finer resolution** (smaller pixels), or vector graphics.

The image should consistently use **two different colours** for points satisfying the condition ("active" pixels) or not satisfying it ("inactive").

## Additional rules

- Graphical output is required, in [any format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges). (ASCII art is not allowed because of size limitations and aspect ratio).
- Both axes should have the **same scale**. The \$x\$ axis should be horizontal, and can consistently increase left to right or right to left. Similarly, the \$y\$ axis should be vertical and can consistently increase upwards or downwards.
- Axis labels, auxiliary grid lines and similar elements are allowed.
- The output image can have an arbitrarily large "**frame**" of inactive pixels around the set of active pixels.
- The set of active points is guaranteed to be **non-empty**.
- Input format is [flexible as usual](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). A [program or a function can be provided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet). [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- The code should work in theory for inputs containing arbitrarily large numbers. In practice, it is acceptable if the program is limited by time, memory or data-type restrictions.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

Input is shown as a list of \$n\$ foci defined as coordinate pairs, followed by \$t\$, and an optional comment.

In the output images, \$x\$ axis increases left to right, \$y\$ axis increases upwards.

```
(5,8), 100  % A circle
```

[image]

```
(0,0), (70, 150), 220  % An ellipse
```

[image]

```
(-100, 0), (100, 0), (100, 0), 480  % Repeated point
```

[image]

```
(-90, -90), (-90, 90), (90, -90), (90, 90), (90, -90), 670  % Repeated; arbitrary order
```

[image]

```
(200, 600), (320, -60), (-350, 220), (-410, 130), (40, -140), 2100
```

[image]

```
(-250, -250), (-250, 250), (250, -250), 1000
```

[image]

```
(-250, -250), (-250, 250), (250, -250), 1200
```

[image]

```
(-390, 0), (-130, 120), (130, -120), (390, 0), 1180  % Finally, a pair of lips?
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for a week title

Comment: I read through the link on acceptable input/output methods. Can we output a gray-scale image in the format of a matrix of floats between 0 and 1?

Comment: @RGS I think you mean [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18304/36398), which doesn't seem to have enough community support, so I'm going to say no (sorry)

Comment: Now I know where guitar picks come from!

Comment: @Kaddath Those were my thoughts too (guitar player here)

Comment: @LuisMendo What about [this](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html)? By the way, I like the title.

Comment: @DavidConrad Sure! It’s a standard format, so go ahead. And thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>36</s>  35 bytes

```
«/_⁹r»/+¥,þ/_Ɱ⁸²§½S>⁹µ;L;ZL$;1ṚK”P;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qav34R407iw7t1tc@tFTn8D4gd@O6R407Dm06tPzQ3mA7oOShrdY@1lE@KtaGD3fO8n7UMDfA@v///xoGOgaaOgoa5joKhqaa/42MAA)

A full program that takes a list of lists of integers as the first argument, representing the foci, and the threshold as an integer as its second argument. Prints a PBM file to STDOUT.

#### Example

- First argument: `(0,0), (7, 15)`
- Second argument: `220`
- Output (converted to PNG):
  [image]

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy + pylab, <s>168</s> <s>163</s> 156 bytes

```python
import numpy,pylab
f,t=eval(input())
s=max(map(abs,sum(f,())))+t
k=numpy.r_[-s:s+1]
pylab.imsave('a.png',sum(((k-x)**2+(k[:,None]-y)**2)**.5for x,y in f)>t)
```

Outputs to a file called `a.png`, the y-axis increases downwards.

**Sample outputs** (click for full-res versions)

`[(5, 8)], 100`:

[image]

`[(0, 0), (70, 150)], 220`:

[image]

`[(-90, -90), (-90, 90), (90, -90), (90, 90), (90, -90)], 670`:

[image]

`[(-390, 0), (-130, 120), (130, -120), (390, 0)], 1180`:

[image]

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 152 bytes

```python
f,t=input()
s=max(map(abs,sum(f,())))+t
w=s*2+1
k=range(-s,s+1)
print'P1',w,w
for y in k:
 for x in k:print+(sum(((a-x)**2+(b-y)**2)**.5for a,b in f)>t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwFET3OUV2/m@@xQhCEdIzdF@6iNC0IsaQRNTTp0k7MDAPHuPO@Fltl5KhqCbrtgjIglr0AYt2oMdAYVvAEGCOiGxXoe6EZLPy2r5f0GRBSGTOTzZWd1nRTjszq@cnnyyfB8YLHH/4WQLKJYBuDqzzGYzNWUbupS@yprHoBm8RU3pAT1d8Epdt@wU)

Outputs a [PBM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html) file to STDOUT. Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to output to a file called `a` to save 4 bytes?

Comment: @Noodle9 the `imsave` function needs the file extension to determine the desired file format.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 67 bytes (SBCS)

`⎕IO←0`

```apl
+{(⎕NEW'Bitmap'(⊂'Cbits'(⍵≥+⌿⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)(⊢,-)⍳2×⍵ ⍵))).MakePNG}⊢
```

### NB

- This image is very low contrast (made from a boolean matrix) - the output can be white interior shape on black background by multiplying the boolean matrix:

  +{(⎕NEW'Bitmap'(⊂'Cbits'(16777215×~⍵≥+⌿⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)(⊢,-)⍳2×⍵ ⍵))).MakePNG}⊢
- Images are transposed compared to many other solutions, but you can flip the indices of each focus
- Only works on Dyalog for Windows

### Explanation

This function is a 3-train (fork), the arguments to the inner function are the results of the outer functions:

```apl
+
```

`+` (plus): Translate the image by adding distance to the foci (please comment if this is a misinterpretation of the challenge)

```apl
⊢
```

`⊢` (right): given two arguments (left and right), return the right argument

APL is parsed (glossing over some binding rules) as Brackets, long Right scope, short Left scope. We break it down as follows:

```apl
⍳2×⍵ ⍵
```

Indices from 0 to 2×⍵ in 2 dimensions (our integer pixels)

```apl
(⊢,-)⍳2×⍵
```

`(⊢,-)` (Same catenate negate) to cover positive and negative coordinates

```apl
(.5*⍨-+.×-)
```

Euclidean distance from focus to pixel...

```apl
⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)
```

... applied between each focus and every pixel

```apl
+⌿⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)
```

Sum the distances between all foci and each pixel (n-ellipse)

```apl
⍵≥+⌿⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)
```

Boolean matrix where 1 indicates interior (active) pixels (i.e. sum of distances between foci and pixel is less than *t*)

```apl
(⎕NEW'Bitmap'(⊂'Cbits'(*boolean matrix*))).MakePNG
```

Output signed integer PNG. This can be written to file using

```apl
∇  WritePNG png;tn
   tn←'img.png'⎕NCREATE 0
   png ⎕NAPPEND tn 83
   ⎕NUNTIE tn
∇
```

### Output Images

First is to demonstrate, the written PNG has very low contrast

```apl
f ← +{(⎕NEW'Bitmap'(⊂'Cbits'(⍵≥+⌿⍺∘.(.5*⍨-+.×-)(⊢,-)⍳2×⍵ ⍵))).MakePNG}⊢
WritePNG 5 8 f 100
```

[image]
Below I'm using the black and white version.

```apl
WritePNG (0 0)(70 150) f 220
```

[image]

```apl
WritePNG (¯100 0)(100 0)(100 0) f 480
```

[image]

Very resource hungry algorithm so I did a low res version of this

```apl
WritePNG (20 60)(32 ¯6)(¯35 22)(¯41 13)(4 ¯14) f 210
```

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps include a couple of screenshots of your results?

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>212</s> 196 bytes

```js
with(Math)f=(c,l,...p)=>{m=l-max(...p)
c.height=c.width=s=min(...p)+l+m
for(i=0;i<s;i++)for(j=0;j<s;j++){for(d=k=0;1/p[k];)d+=hypot(p[k++]+m-i,p[k++]+m-j)
d>l||c.getContext`2d`.fillRect(i,j,1,1)}}

eval(`f(c,${e.value})`)
```

```css
input{position:fixed}
```

```html
<input id=e oninput=eval(`f(c,${e.value})`) value="100,-25,-25,-25,25,25,-25"><canvas id=c>
```

Outputs via first parameter which is a canvas element to draw on, second parameter is the threshold, then the remaining parameters are the loci. Edit: Saved 16 bytes thanks to @Arnauld, however the code is now dead slow and will trigger slow script warnings for large thresholds.

Comment: @LuisMendo Running the snippet itself doesn't actually trigger the input event that calls the function, so the suggested input doesn't run unless you edit the value e.g. by appending a space.

Comment: [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pck9D4IwFIXhnV/SpqWKK14XZxdXYwJpi721BSI3fgT47Vg1cTvPe3x9rwd9w57ytjN2WR5Ijh1qcrwBpmWQSqmew26MEPJYP9nXmVbO4sURaPVAQw4GiNj@ThFEzJruxhDWJW6HEoXgH/tkn@yTx08wcE2pWPWn67nkRoB79R2xRCHOIuYo/9PzzOzCNGl1sbTvWrJPqjamUg2GcLSaGEovC1nweV6WNw), I think (not really tested).

Comment: @LuisMendo I've added an extra line to calculate the suggestion automatically.

Comment: @Arnauld Boy that's slow :-(

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [Gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss), 165 bytes

```hs
import Graphics.Gloss
i=fromIntegral
h t=[i(-t)*3..i t*3]
d f t=display(InWindow""(t*3,t*3)(0,0))red$Line[(x,y)|x<-h t,y<-h t,i t>sum[sqrt$(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2|(u,v)<-f]]
```

Draws the shapes to the screen. It sometimes draws the images REALLY BIG, so I have cropped accordingly.

`main = d [(5,8)] 100`

[image]

`main = d [(0,0), (70, 150)] 220`

[image]

`main = d [(-100, 0), (100, 0), (100, 0)] 480`

[image]

`main = d [(-250, -250), (-250, 250), (250, -250)] 1000`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 300 bytes

```
Red[]f: func[p t][a: :absolute 
m: last sort collect[foreach n p[keep a n/x keep a n/y]]s: t + m * 2
u: as-pair s s i: make image! reduce[u]k: 0 repeat y s[repeat x s[d: 0
foreach a p[d: d +(sqrt x - t - m - a/x ** 2 +(y - t - m - a/y ** 2))]k: k + 1
if d <= t[i/:k: 0.0.255]]]save/as %1.jpg i 'jpeg]
```

`f [5x8] 100`

[image]

`f [0x0 70x150] 220`

[image]

`f [-100x0 100x0 100x0] 480`

[image]

`f [200x600 320x-60 -350x220 -410x130 40x-140] 2100`

[image]

`f [-390x0 -130x120 130x-120 390x0] 1180`

[image]

Note: I scaled all the images to 256x256 pixels and croped the last two images so that they don't take too much space - they had a large "frame"

Answer (score 4):

## Applescript + grapher, 601

This will almost certainly be the longest answer, but I thought this would be a fun challenge in Applescript.

```applescript
on f(l, t)
set y to 0
tell application "Grapher" to activate
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "n" using command down
keystroke return
keystroke "a" using command down
repeat with d in l
keystroke "sqrt((x-"&d's item 1&")^2)+(y-"&d's item 2&")^2))+"
set y to y+d's item 2
end repeat
click application process "Grapher"'s menu bar 1's menu bar item 8's menu 1's menu item 3
set c to l's items count
keystroke "             "&(y-t)/c as text&" "&(y+t)/c as text&"     "
keystroke "c" using command down
keystroke "             "
keystroke "v" using command down
keystroke return&"0<"&t as text&return
end tell
end f
```

This is an applescript function.  It may be called as follows for the testcases:

```applescript
my f({{5, 8}}, 100)
my f({{0, 0}, {70, 150}}, 220)
my f({{-100, 0}, {100, 0}, {100, 0}}, 480)
my f({{-90, -90}, {-90, 90}, {90, -90}, {90, 90}, {90, -90}}, 670)
my f({{200, 600}, {320, -60}, {-350, 220}, {-410, 130}, {40, -140}}, 2100)
my f({{-250, -250}, {-250, 250}, {250, -250}}, 1000)
my f({{-250, -250}, {-250, 250}, {250, -250}}, 1200)
my f({{-390, 0}, {-130, 120}, {130, -120}, {390, 0}}, 1180)
```

Output looks like this, e.g. for the 5th testcase:

[image]

Comment: This looks a lot like natural language:-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Apparently that's the idea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Natural_language_metaphor

Comment: Very much Apple-like

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB + [DIPimage](https://diplib.github.io/DIPimage.html) toolbox, <s>133</s> <s>121</s> <s>117</s> 111 bytes

(shaved off <s>12</s> 16 bytes thanks to flawr and LuisMendo)

```matlab
function s(c,r),c=c-min(c)+r;a=zeros(max(c)+r);l='corner';for x=c',a=a+hypot(xx(a,l)-x(1),yy(a,l)-x(2));end,a>r
```

Use:

```matlab
c = [-390, 0; -130, 120; 130, -120; 390, 0];
r = 1180;
s(c,r)
```

In a more readable fashion:

```matlab
function s(c,r)
c=c-min(c)+r;           % offset coordinates so all points within shape have non-negative coordinates
a=zeros(max(c)+r);      % compute image size and create empty output image
l='corner';             % long argument used twice below
for x=c'
   a=a+hypot(xx(a,l)-x(1),yy(a,l)-x(2)); % add distance to each point
end
a>r                     % threshold and display (leaving semi-colon off causes graphical display of image)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
\sum_{n=1}^c \sqrt{(x-a[n].x)^2+(y-a[n].y)^2}<=t
```

-1 byte from finding a new quirk in Desmos' syntax while working on another problem.

[View it online](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ps2nlafz9g)

It just kinda... works. Input `n` in the variable `c`, `t` in the variable `t`, and the points as an array `a` of coordinates.

Lips example:

[image: "lips" n-ellipse in Desmos]

Guitar pick example:

[image: "guitar pick" n-ellipse in Desmos]

Note: If you try to copy the equation from the editor, you'll find a bunch of `\left`s and `\right`s and such. These have been golfed out of this answer, as you can paste this text in and it works. The editor automatically re-adds those when parsing input from the clipboard, but it accepts the code without them.

Note two: I'm not 100% sure if this counts due to the infill being transparent, but hopefully it's ok. If not, there's a couple options:

1. Stack a bunch of whole bunch of these equations on top of each other. I tried this and it turns out that a quirk of their rendering engine is that the fill color can never drop below #010101, while the outline is at #000000. Additionally, the area is a little larger than would be ideal because the outline looks like part of the fill.
2. Rewrite the n-ellipse equation in parametric form. I don't know if this is possible or not, but if it is, Desmos's enhanced visual options for parametric equations allows us to remove the outline.

Comment: Right tool for the job :-) Fill being half-transparent is ok

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Standard utilities (but no graphics library), <s>194</s> <s>190</s> 186 bytes

```bash
t=$1
shift
L=H=$1
for n do
L=$[n<L?n:L]
H=$[n>H?n:H]
done
echo P2 $[L-=t,H+=t+1,H-L] $[H-L] 1
for((x=y=L;y<H;++x>=H?x=L,y++:0)){ bc -l<<<`printf "sqrt(($x- %d)^2+($y- %d)^2)+" $@`0\>$t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw9C4MwGATgPb/iRVKIxIAKhaKJdsyQobu1WL9QKLHVDJHS355q6XT33HD1fRmcMwJHaBnG3iAl5I5@mkFDO23GheYq14kqkdyRyQ2yRO2kO9Q1wwSXGHChmDCBpMLQKJBMldv0i98XIVasQqUrlymlNhMyt0IFK6VJ6PtvqBtgD8559ZxHbXrwltdsCMGWwaH1bzEleP1Xn3qAz1V4zbBJP865KAzd0Z2@) (If you do, though, try a tiny example: even the circle test times out on TIO.)

---

Input is passed in the arguments: first \$t\$, then \$x_1\$, \$y_1\$, \$x_2\$, \$y_2\$, ..., \$x_n\$, \$y_n\$.

Output is a PGM image on stdout.  Save it in a file named `something.pgm` and view it in your favorite graphics program.

The x-axis goes from left to right, and the y-axis goes from top to bottom.  White is the background, and black is the n-ellipse being drawn.

For example, to view the first example (the circle), you could execute:

```bash
lips 100 5 8 > lips-circle.pgm
```

(where the program is named `lips`).  Then open the image`lips-circle.pgm`.  Here's the result:
[image]

Here's the second test, the output of `lips 220 0 0 70 150 > lips-ellipse.pgm`:[image]

Next is `lips 480 -100 0 100 0 100 0 > lips-repeatedpoint.pgm`:

[image]

Here is `lips 670 -90 -90 -90 90 90 -90 90 90 90 -90 > lips-repeated-arbitaryOrder.pgm`:

[image]

The next test is `lips 2100 200 600 320 -60 -350 220 -410 130 40 -140 > lips-shape1.pgm`:

[image]

---

*This script is very slow (but runnable).  I will post more sample images as my computer gets around to finishing them :) ....*

*Well, after waiting overnight again, the other tests are finally done!*

---

Here's the guitar pick: `lips 1000 -250 -250 -250 250 250 -250 > lips-guitarpick.pgm`
[image]

The next test is `lips 1200 -250 -250 -250 250 250 -250 > lips-shape2.pgm`:
[image]

And finally the pair of lips! `lips 1180 -390 0 -130 120 130 -120 390 0 > lips-pairOfLips.pgm`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Shadertoy (GLSL) 125 bytes + input data

```
vec2 a[]=vec2[](vec2(-390, 0),vec2(-130,120),vec2(130,-120),vec2(390,0));
float d=1180.;

void mainImage(out vec4 o,vec2 c){c-=iResolution.xy/2.;o-=o;for(int i=0;i<a.length();o.a+=length(c-a[i++]));o.b=step(o.a,d);}
```

[Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ttVXW3) link for the last testcase.

As the input array's size is known, this could be further reduced by replacing the `a.length()` by `n`.

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: Also, why don't you do the further reduction you suggest in your answer?

Comment: it doesn't receive input, I could change it to a uniform value but that's still not like in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 39 bytes

```
\distance((x,y),\ans_0).\total<=\ans_1
```

The other Desmos answer to this challenge is invalid because it assumes that the input is stored in hardcoded variables, which is [heavily](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/96039) [discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2423/96039).

Instead, this program takes input through `\ans`, which is an [acceptable form of input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8580/96039).

Input the list of points in the first line, and the threshold in the second line.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7wwa6edioa)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vghn0l7hhp)